# Drawing a curve

Tags: c#, graph

trying to draw a quadratic function, where the user enters a, b, c (ax^2 + bx + c). I have made a function to calculate the roots, now i must try and draw the graph. I have copied microsofts example of a bezier curve, it compiles but then there is no output. Any help would be great

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;


     namespace graph
      { 
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void drawBeziers(Pen pen, Point[] coordinates)
    {
    }
    private void quadGraph(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

      Point start = new Point(100, 100);
      Point control1 = new Point(200, 10);
      Point control2 = new Point(350, 50);
      Point end1 = new Point(500, 100);
      Point control3 = new Point(600, 150);
      Point control4 = new Point(650, 250);
      Point end2 = new Point(500, 300);
      Point[] bezierPoints = 
                 {
                     start, control1, control2, end1, 
                     control3, control4, end2
                 };

      e.Graphics.DrawBeziers(blackPen, bezierPoints);



    }
```

Comment: you dont even call quadGraph()....

Answer (score 0):

You dont even call quadGraph(), add this to your class:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
   base.OnPaint(pe);
   quadGraph(pe);
}
```